# Minicart failed to load component Magento 2

Tags: magento, minicart

I am trying to add a new custom component to my minicart. Its working perfectly on the cart page but I get this error anywhere else "[ERROR] Failed to load the "Heartfelt_Platinum/js/view/summary/minicart-platinum-clarification" component." Can anyone help me understand why my component is failing to load?

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" src="Heartfelt_Platinum::css/minicart-platinum-clarification.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="minicart-platinum-clarification" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Heartfelt_Platinum/js/view/summary/minicart-platinum-clarification</item>
                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Heartfelt_Platinum/cart/totals/minicart-platinum-clarification</item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="array">0</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'mage/translate'
], function (
    $,
    ko,
    Component,
    quote,
    customer,
    $t
) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Heartfelt_Platinum/cart/totals/minicart-platinum-clarification'
        },

        isCustomerLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn,
        groupId: customer['customerData']['group_id'],

        getNotLoggedInText: function () {
            return $t('Become Platinum Member, Save 20%');
        },

        getLoggedInText: function () {
            return $t('20% Platinum Savings Applied');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the file "'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'," is not allowed in the minicart. It was removed and it loaded the file perfectly.